# How to detect neck with Face Detection API available in Core Image

Tags: ios

I am developing an application in which i have to detect a face with neck from image taken from gallery or camera. i am using the following link to detect the face

[Face detection tutorial link](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5)

and its detecting the face very well but i can't find any solution how to detect neck. i have to set the detected face on another face of another image.
please suggest me how to do it with core image.

Comment: It's usually underneath the face.

Comment: Why do you ask the question twice within a short time? Usually, you should only ask once and wait for answers!

Comment: I wana do the same. Any lead ?